# RStudio splitting console and source panes

Tags: rstudio

A couple days ago my RStudio began to maximize/minimize the source and console windows with no option to change the length or split them so that you can see both. I'm not sure what I did and I can't find an option to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, panes can only be adjusted at the bottom right hand corner.